# How to ignore subdirectories with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, server

How can I configure my `.htaccess` to ignore subdirectories?

For example, this...

```
site.com/archive/2014
site.com/archive/2014/12
site.com/archive/xyz
```

should show the content of...

```
site.com/archive/
```

regardless of the subdirectory.

Comment: Are any of those actually physically existing folders, and if so, do you want to treat them differently from non-existing ones?

Comment: Ignore from what? Please share what it is you currently have in your htaccess and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You could always add a htaccess-file in the sub directory that overrides the top level htaccess.

Comment: @cbroe no they are not existing folders.

Comment: @magnus i dont want to always return error 404 so i would rather all sub directories display same thing as the main directory

Comment: We still need to see your current implementation.

Comment: Use RewriteCond to check if what was requested is not an existing file or folder (flags -f/-d), and if so rewrite every request that starts with `archive/` and has arbitrary characters behind that back to `archive/`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following, using mod_rewrite, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^archive/. /archive/ [R,L]
```

What this says is... for any request that starts `/archive/<something>` that does not map to a physical file or directory then redirect to `/archive/`.

Note that this is an external redirect (as opposed to an *internal rewrite*, which you appear to suggest in your question) so as to avoid potential *duplicate content*.